# read in a file and use awk to edit the output

Tags: bash, command-line, awk

This a the file that I read in

```
Ford:Mondeo:1997:Blue:5
Vauxhall:Vectra:1999:White:2
Seat:Ibiza:1996:Red:4
Ford:Puma:2000:Black:1
Ford:Fiesta:1995:Red:2
Ford:Focus:2001:Black:0
Subaru:Impreza:1998:Green:1
Vauxhall:Corsa:1999:White:5
Honda:Accord:2004:Red:1
PEUGEOT:206:2000:Black:1
Ford:Fiesta:2000:Red:2
Rover:200:1993:Green:7
Ford:Mondeo:2001:Blue:0
Vauxhall:Cavalier:1995:White:2
Volkswagen:Beetle:2001:Blue:0
Ford:Escort:1995:Green:3
Skoda:Fabia:2006:Red:1
Vauxhall:Nova:1994:Black:8
Rover:Metro:1996:Burgundy:3
Renault:Megane:2006:Blue:4
Peugeot:406:1999:Silver:1
McLaren:F1:1997:Black:2
Skoda:Octavia:2003:Silver:2
Peugeot:206:2000:Red:1
```

Using awk I want reformat the output so I get this

```
Car: Ford Mondeo, made in 1997, no previous owners.
Car: Ford Mondeo, made in 2000, 1 previous owner(s).
Car: Ford Mondeo, made in 2001, 2 previous owner(s).
```

This is the command I have got so far

```
awk -F: { printf "Car:%s %s, made in %s, no previous owners.", $1=="Ford" && $2=="Mondeo" && $3  < 2002 && $3 > 1996 } inputfile
```

There is no Ford Mondeo made in 2000 on the original list.

Comment: And what's missing? The 0 -> no mapping for the last column?

Comment: That command is clearly not the command used to generate that output, so my guess is that your input is also not what you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be a more elegant solution but this works for me. Just add the path to your file at the end.

```
awk -F ":" '{ printf "Car: "$1" "$2", made in " $3", "; if($5 == "0") {printf "no previous owners.\n"} else {printf $5" previous owner(s).\n"}}'
```

**Edit:**
I just realized you may only be looking for cars that are specifically a Ford Mondeo (your question isn't exactly clear). In that case this awk command should work. Piping the previous commands output to grep might be a little bit easier to understand though.

```
awk -F ":" '{ if ($1 == "Ford" && $2 == "Mondeo") {printf "Car: "$1" "$2", made in " $3", "} else {next}; if($5 == "0") {printf "no previous owners.\n"} else {printf $5" previous owner(s).\n"}}'
```

Comment: I am looking for only Ford Mondeo cars aswell as adding one. I am trying to get the output exactly like the one in my question. The $5 is not the number of owners so I would like to ignore that.

Comment: Then I am really quite confused as to what you are wanting this awk command to do. If one car is completely missing from the list and you are pulling the number of previous owners out of air then where are you getting that from? What is even the point of the awk command at that point? You would almost be hard coding half of your output. Are you sure your input is correct?